# does an Ubuntu upgrade use the same disk as the current version

Tags: ubuntu

So I have a spinning disk and an SSD. Ubuntu 13.10 is installed on the SSD which makes everything so much faster. I want to upgrade to 14.04. Will it be installed on the same SSD disk or might it go onto the spinning disk? Obviously I want it on the SSD. Thanks

Comment: about upgrading in general: http://askubuntu.com/questions/110477/how-do-i-upgrade-to-a-newer-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: so why down tick the question? Not everyone knows everything. Tsk

Comment: The downvotes are because your question is off-topic. Hover your mouse over the down arrow and you'll see the explanation. In this case the question is 'not useful'. Bear in mind that it's 'not useful' on a programming site. Elsewhere it might be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ubuntu upgrade will upgrade your existing packages. If you currently have them installed on the SSD, the upgrade will be there too.